# Unable to push code to github as a collaborator

Tags: github, git-push, personal-access-token

Whenever I'm trying to push my code to github as a collaborator I'm getting an error saying I don't have enough permission with error 403, although I'm added as a collaborator. I'm using linux.

I've created a personal access token for the account where I'm going to contribute (yes that's my account also) and used that token as password at the time of pushing and it worked but I know it's a workaround and not the actual method. How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried logging in with OAuth2?

Comment: This is up to GitHub (and I'm no expert there) but as far as I know, your method *is* the *actual method* and not a workaround at all.

Comment: @dan1st No I haven't, can u explain how to please?

Comment: @torek maybe, but still I need to put my username and password every time I try to push code.